# How to move unopen files to another folder

Tags: bash, script, centos-7

I´m beginner in Linux and I want to build a script in bash to check which files are open in a folder and move any other files - those that are not open to another folder.

Comment: And how do you think the system will know that a file has been opened? This would only be possible by using an application that updated some metadata when the user accesses the file.

Comment: What about lsof ?

Comment: That checks what is actually open. That is not implied by your question. The wording implied you wanted to check what had been opened/unopened not what was currently opened/unopened which is a different thing altogether.

Comment: Correct, I want to check what is actually open - I´m not native english speaker.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of clarifying the wording.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of an entirely elegant way to do this. I was hoping that `find` would have some facility for this. That would have made this easy. But I didn't find an option for identifying a file as open so I went with making a small script to get the logic down.

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=/some/files
NEW_DIR=/some/new/files
OPEN_FILES=$(lsof -Fn $DIR/* | grep ^n | cut -c2- | sort -u)
for file in $DIR/*; do
    if echo "$OPEN_FILES" | grep -q $file; then
        echo "$file is opened - not moving"
        continue
    fi
    mv $file $NEW_DIR/
    echo "$file moved"
done
```

It's kind of gross, honestly, but hopefully it's the basis of what you want and you can modify more as needed. If anybody knows of a way to do this with `find`, please chime in. `find` with `-exec mv` option is really good for stuff like this.